# Can Entity Class be inherited from Value Object?

Tags: domain-driven-design

In my business domain an entity "CompanyPrefix" appears to extend a VO CompanyPrefixVO that keeps all business rules. No other class would be using this VO. As a good practice:

1. should I extend CompanyPrefix from CompanyPrefixVO? or
2. drop the VO and merge business rules into entity CompanyPrefix? or
3. CompanyPrefix should only be associated with CompanyPrefixVO? or
4. something totally different?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inheritance can lead to many problems, first of all high coupling and strong dependencies which can hinder your domain model from evolving. I'd use composition instead. The Value Object can be part of the Entity.

That said I'd also ask a few questions: What kind of business entity would CompanyPrefix be? Is it not just part of a name or identifier? Does it have a lifecycle of its own, i.e. does it change its properties over time? Why does the prefix need an ID? Just for normalization (aka database details that don't belong in the domain model?)

I don't know your specific case but there simply might be a VO representing a company prefix as part of the company.

Comment: Thankyou @Dennis Traub. CompanyPrefix has its own life cycle. Company can have multiple companyPrefixes provided by different identity providers that may get obsolete over time as well. So Company prefix is clearly an entity, though entity name is bit confusing. It is actually globally unique company Identifier.
I got your point regarding inheritance but on the other hand company.companyPrefix.CompanyPrefixVO.value is looking bit odd to me.

Comment: Then I'd merge both into the prefix. Apart from that it is considered bad practice to reach through one object to directly retrieve the property of an included object. The containing object usually would encapsulate the access to the inner object. Google "Tell don't ask" or "Law of Demeter" for more info.